# Homotopy type of the loop space of a compact Lie group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, morse-theory

The following theorem is proved in Milnor's famous book "Morse theory".

Theorem 21.7 (Bott). Let $G$ be a compact, simply connected Lie group. Then the loop space of $G$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex with no odd dimensional cells.

It is not clear to me where the author uses the simply connectedness of $G$. Is it a necessary condition?  Can someone please illuminate?

Comment: No. Milnor shows that the space of maps $Map(X,Y)$ (compact-open topology) is CW whenever $X,Y$ are CW, $X$ is finite and $Y$ is countable and locally finite. I think this can be improved somewhat, but I don't have a reference off the top of my head. (In any case it applies fo $\Omega G=Map((S^1,\ast),(G,\ast))$ for all compact Lie groups $G$, no simple connectedness needed).

Comment: Thanks! @Tyrone.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily drop the connectivity condition as long as each (equivalently, one) component is simply-connected. But the assumption that $\pi_1(X)=1$,  is a necessary condition. If $X$ is a complex without odd-dimensional cells then $\pi_1(X)=1$: Indeed, by the cellular approximation theorem, every loop $c$ in $X$ is homotopic to a loop $c'$ in $X^1$. If $X^1$ contains no 1-cells, then $X^1=X^0$, implying that $c'$ is constant. Thus, $\pi_1(X)=1$.